# Formato Fecha Mysql - Case when

Tags: mysql, laravel

Problema:
Tengo una tabla donde se encuentran las personas que han aprobado varios cursos, cuando los listo me muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
$data_generals = DB::table('historico')
    ->select(DB::raw('dni,participante,
        (CASE WHEN id_curso = 13 and nota > 15 THEN fecha ELSE 0 END) AS curso1,
        (CASE WHEN id_curso = 17 and nota > 15 THEN fecha ELSE 0 END) AS curso2,
        (CASE WHEN id_curso = 18 and nota > 15 THEN fecha ELSE 0 END) AS curso3,
        (CASE WHEN id_curso = 18 and nota > 15 THEN fecha ELSE 0 END) AS curso4'))
    ->whereIn('id_curso',[13,17,18,20])
    ->groupBy('dni','participante','id_curso','nota','fecha')
    ->orderBy('dni','asc')
    ->paginate(100);
```

LO QUE NECESITO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que tipo de dato es fecha?

Comment: si tipo date y en mysql se muestra yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: ahora la duda por que deseas hacer una concatenación? es decir la forma en la que se guarda el dato y lo que tratas de hacer no es mas de lo mismo?

Comment: Es muy confuso, veo una fecha, una suma, una concatenación, un date_format... ¿qué es lo que pretendes hacer?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es convertir las filas en columnas, Osea si el participante llevo el curso 1 que aparesca la fecha en la que lo llevo

Comment: ¿Qué significa llevar el curso?

Comment: haber aprobado el curso

Comment: Estás intentando sumar las fechas? Es lo que observo, fuera del todo haces una suma en que si cumple una funcion entonces sume las fechas

Comment: He modificado mi codigo y mi pregunta para que sea mas entendible, haber si me pueden ayudar por favor.

Comment: gracias @gbianchi pero como haría entonces la validación si esta aprobado?

Comment: Si existe el curso en la otra tabla y tiene una fecha de aprobacion, esta aprobado ;)

Comment: Creo que entendi mal tu tabla original.. no es la primera que mostras no? podrias mostrar como guardas los datos? a ver si de ahi podemos construir el query y alguien lo puede traducir a laravel. Mi comentario anterior esta mal.

Comment: Para ello usa la funcion PIVOT GROUP de manera dinámica, te agrupara todos los cursos en columnas separadas http://webdevzoom.com/dynamic-pivot-table-using-mysql/ ese link me fue de gran ayuda cuando necesite una matriz como la que tienes.